# How do I make my plotly dash app interactive when hovering over an item in a table?

Tags: python, charts, hover, plotly-dash, interactive

Using plotly dash, I want to build an interactive tool for the best 10 coffee shops in Philadelphia, as well as map out all of the coffee shops in Philadelphia, but I'm having trouble implementing the interactivity portion.

I have a dataframe called philly_reviews_asba with columns:

```
['business_id', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code','latitude', 'longitude', 'stars_x', 'review_count', 'is_open', 'attributes', 'categories', 'hours', 'review_id', 'user_id', 'stars_y', 'useful', 'funny', 'cool', 'text', 'date', 'pss', 'positive','metric_1', 'metric_2', 'composite_score']
```

I have a dataframe called top_10_coffee_shops with columns:

```
['business_id', 'composite_score', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'stars_x', 'review_count', 'is_open', 'attributes', 'categories', 'hours']
```

I have another dataframe called bi_grams_results with columns: ['name', 'business_id', 'bigram', 'frequency'], which shows the top 10 frequent bi-grams for each of the top 10 coffee shops as per our computed composite score.

Just to clarify, philly_reviews_asba would contain all of the coffee shops in philly while top_10_coffee_shops only includes the top 10

Within the app itself, I currently have a table of the top 10 coffee shops alongside their rankings (#1-10) and their composite scores. To the right, I have a map of Philadelphia with markers for all of the coffee shops so that when you hover over a marker, it displays information such as name, composite score, etc

1. How do I make it so that whenever you hover over a coffee shop in the top 10 list, the marker pops up and acts as if you had hovered over the dot yourself?
2. How do I make it so that whenever you hover over a coffee shop in the top 10 list, a horizontal bar graph of the bi-gram frequencies for that particular coffee shop appears below the table and map? (preferably in the center). Right now I just see an empty graph with x and y axes.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
from dash.dash_table import DataTable
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Load your dataframes
philly_reviews_asba = pd.read_csv('../Data/philly_reviews_asba.csv')
philly_reviews_asba = philly_reviews_asba.iloc[:, 1:]
top_10_coffee_shops = pd.read_csv('../Data/top_10_coffee_shops.csv')
top_10_coffee_shops = top_10_coffee_shops.iloc[:, 1:]
bi_grams_results = pd.read_csv('../Data/top_10_bigrams.csv')
bi_grams_results = bi_grams_results.iloc[:, 1:]

# Create Dash app
app = Dash(__name__)

# Define layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Philadelphia Coffee Shops', style={'textAlign': 'center'}),

    # Two columns layout: Left (List of Top 10) and Right (Map + Bar Chart)
    html.Div([
        # Left Column: List of Top 10 Coffee Shops
        html.Div([
            html.H2(children='Top 10 Coffee Shops'),
            DataTable(id='top-10-table', columns=[]),
        ], style={'width': '30%', 'float': 'left', 'margin-right': '5%'}),

        # Right Column: Map of all coffee shops and Bar chart of top bigrams
        html.Div([
            # Map of all coffee shops
            dcc.Graph(id='map-all-coffee-shops', style={'width': '100%'}),

            # Bar chart of top bigrams
            dcc.Graph(id='top-bigrams-chart', style={'width': '100%'}),
        ], style={'width': '65%', 'float': 'left'}),
    ]),
])

# Callback to update the map and bigrams chart based on selected coffee shop
@app.callback(
    Output('map-all-coffee-shops', 'figure'),
    Output('top-bigrams-chart', 'figure'),
    Input('top-10-table', 'active_cell'),
)
def update_map_and_chart(active_cell):
    if active_cell is None:
        # If no cell is selected, return an empty map and bigram chart
        empty_map = px.scatter_mapbox(
            lat=[],
            lon=[],
            text=[],
            zoom=10,
            height=500,
        )

        empty_chart = px.bar(title='Top 10 Bigrams')
        return empty_map, empty_chart

    # Get the selected coffee shop
    selected_shop = top_10_coffee_shops.iloc[active_cell['row']]

    # Group by business name and calculate the average composite score
    avg_composite_scores = philly_reviews_asba.groupby('name')['composite_score'].mean().reset_index()

    # Update the map with the selected coffee shop highlighted
    fig_map = px.scatter_mapbox(
        avg_composite_scores,  # Use the grouped data
        lat="latitude",
        lon="longitude",
        text=["Name: {}<br>Avg Composite Score: {}".format(name, score) for name, score in zip(avg_composite_scores['name'], avg_composite_scores['composite_score'])],
        color_discrete_sequence=["blue"],
        zoom=10,
        height=500,
    )

    selected_lat = selected_shop['latitude']
    selected_lon = selected_shop['longitude']

    # Highlight/enlarge the marker
    fig_map.add_trace(
        go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=[selected_lat],
            lon=[selected_lon],
            text=["Name: {}<br>Avg Composite Score: {}".format(selected_shop['name'], selected_shop['composite_score'])],
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=15, color='red'),
            showlegend=False,
        )
    )

    fig_map.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")

    # Update the bigrams chart with the selected coffee shop's bigrams
    fig_bigrams = px.bar(
        bi_grams_results[bi_grams_results['business_id'] == selected_shop['business_id']],
        x='bigram',
        y='frequency',
        title=f'Top 10 Bigrams for {selected_shop["name"]}',
    )

    return fig_map, fig_bigrams


# Callback to update the top 10 coffee shops table
@app.callback(
    Output('top-10-table', 'columns'),
    Output('top-10-table', 'data'),
    Input('map-all-coffee-shops', 'hoverData'),
)
def update_top_10_table(hover_data):
    if hover_data is None or 'points' not in hover_data:
        # If no hover data or points, return an empty table
        empty_columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in ['Rank', 'Coffee Shop', 'Composite Score']]
        empty_data = []
        return empty_columns, empty_data

    # Get the name of the hovered coffee shop
    hovered_shop_name = hover_data['points'][0]['text']

    # Find the corresponding coffee shop in the top 10
    hovered_shop = top_10_coffee_shops[top_10_coffee_shops['name'] == hovered_shop_name]

    # Display top 10 coffee shops table
    top_10_table = pd.DataFrame({
        'Rank': range(1, 11),
        'Coffee Shop': top_10_coffee_shops['name'],
        'Composite Score': top_10_coffee_shops['composite_score'],
    })

    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in top_10_table.columns]
    data = top_10_table.to_dict('records')

    return columns, data


# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8051, debug=True)
```